# JS data type clarification

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to learn JS and had an exercise where I had to put which value and data type the following would give back:

```
alert(Number(17  / 2 + 1.3))
```

The correct solution was "**undefined**" and "undefined" and I don't understand why? The console does show an alert that says 9.8. Why isn't it "9.8" and "number" then?

Comment: If browser say 9.8 then 9.8 is right answer )

Comment: Also more interesting : Number(17 / 2 + 1.3) = 9.8 but Number(17 / 2 + 1,3) = 9.5

Comment: @S.Nadezhnyy Number constructor ignored the second argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

alert is a function which doesn't return a value.

The way the question is worded, is sounds like that's the idea here. alert() will always 'give back' undefined whatever you actually pass into it.

```
var result = alert(Number(17 / 2 + 1.3))
console.log(result);
console.log(typeof(result));
```

Outputs

undefined
undefined

Comment: Ok, I got it! Thank you very much for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the

```
alert(Number(17 / 2 + 1.3))
```

the value would be `undefined` and the type would be `undefined` but there would be an effect on the browser window where a dialog opens up with the text `9.8` printed in it.

If the question only had

```
Number(17 / 2 + 1.3)
```

then the value would be `9.8` and the type `Number`

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Alert is a method that displays messagebox and will always return undefined.
It would never return values passed to it as argument.

For clarification

```
typeof(Number(17 / 2 + 1.3)) // will return "number"
typeof(alert(Number(17 / 2 + 1.3))) // will return "undefined" (after showing alert box)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> where I had to put which value and data type the following would give
>   back:

Data type of alert is `undefined` since `alert` doesn't return a value.

Data type of `undefined` is also `undefined` (check `typeof undefined`)

Value Ouput is correct only as explained below

As per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tonumber)

> ToNumber applied to Strings applies the following grammar to the input
>   String interpreted as a sequence of UTF-16 encoded code points

As per the operator precedence, divide operation will be executed first so

`alert(Number(17 / 2 + 1.3))` tranlates to `alert(Number(8.5 + 1.3))` -> `alert(Number(9.8))` -> `alert(9.8)`

> Number(17 / 2 + 1.3) = 9.8 but Number(17 / 2 + 1,3) = 9.5

Since Number constructor ignored the second argument.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

"alert" is a function.
As usual, a function's task is to do some operation and then return a value if needed.
As a result:

```
alert(Number(17 / 2 + 1.3))
```

It did the operation: show the result 9.8 in window so you can see it.
But it's return value is undefined actually.